# calculate avarage waiting time in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Two groups of men and women arrive at the same entrance source at the same time to avail a certain service, then how can we get the entire average waiting time of both separately in anylogic .please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these two block provided by AnyLogic.

[image]

Or as I do, create two variables for your agents called `enterTime` and `leaveTime` and set them to `time()` when they enter and leave the Queue. Like `agent.enterTime = time()`. Create a variable in the Main (assuming your blocks are there) called `totalTimeInQueueMen` and `totalTimeInQueueWomen` and set it to `totalTimeInQueueMen=totalTimeInQueueMen+(agent.leaveTime-agent.enterTime)`. Also count your number of agents with a variable called `count`. Every time they enter the queue, increment it by 1; like `count+=1;`. At the end of the the simulation you can calculate the average as `totalTimeInQueueMen/count` (the same for women).

Comment: @ana glad it was useful. Please don't forget to upvote and accept as answer so that others can also benefit.