# Find Average time in different flow paths

Tags: anylogic

Im currently building a Anylogic model and want to calculate average time spent by customer in different flow paths (I have added the process flow below). In the picture i have named the paths i want to calculate the average time as path A and path B
[image: Process flow]

Comment: Please refer to my answer to the previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74177389/9375979

Answer (score 1):

Anyligic has dedicated blocks for this (although it can be done simply in code).
See in detail [here](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/time-in-system.html#measuring-time-in-system).

The `TimeMeasureEnd` block contains a dataset.

The following code returns the average of the Y-axis values:

```
timeMeasureEnd.dataset.getYMean();
```

Good luck!